# Assigning a datarow to at an index of datarows which are getting by a datatable select method, not updating that datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, datatable.select

There is a datatable ( source ), and a copy of this datatable is created ( copy ), and in this copy, some rows are modified in DataGridView.

After modification is over, A method is updating source datatable with modified rows in copy datatable.

```
DataTable source ;// it is population by database.
```

and its copy

```
DataTable copy = source.Copy(); // Here is the copy datatble.
```

The method is like :

```
public static void UpdateData(DataTable source, DataTable copy)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in copy.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
        {
            var relRow = source.Select("Id = '" + row["Id"] + "'");
            if (relRow.Any())
            {
                //relRow[0] = row; //This statement is not udating row in the source dataTable.
                foreach (var column in copy.Columns)
                {
                    relRow[0][column.ColumnName] = row[column.ColumnName];
                }
            }
        } 
        else if (row.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
        {
               //Performing some operations to for checking additional values. modiging 'row' with some relative data, and adding to source.
                source.Rows.Add(row.ItemArray);
        }       
    }

    return source;
}
```

when assigning a row object to datarows array's first element like  `relRow[0] = row`, it is not updating source datatable, but it is showing modified data while debuggin in relRow[0].

Column by column assignment reflecting changes in datatable.

So, The question is : Why `relRow[0] = row` not updating in source datatable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By writing `relRow[0] = row;`, you're simply re-assigning the *reference* of relRow, modifying the 0th element of your local array. It isn't actually changing the contents of the row in the table. Your code is the same as:

```
DataRow[] localRows;
// here, localRows will reference items in the source table. 
// Below, you overwrite the reference.
localRows = source.Select("Id = '" + row["Id"] + "'");
if(localRows.Any())
{
    //changes what reference the 0th element of the localRows array points to,
    // doesn't change anything about the datatable.
    // localRows[0] now points to the local variable row (i.e. the item from copy)
    localRows[0] = row; 
}
```

To modify the table, you can replace `relRow[0] = row;` with something that modifies the *elements* of relRow rather than its reference:

```
for(var col = 0; col < source.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    relRow[0][col] = row[col];
}
```